# Facebook PHP Destroy Session

Tags: php, facebook, session, destroy

Despite me trying for hours on this, I can't figure out why I can't destroy this Facebook session. The logout URL logs out of Facebook, but i can't destroy the session. I've trawled through Stack Overflow but none of the answers have helped so far.

```
session_start();
$app_id = 'XXX';
$app_secret = 'XXX';
$redirect_uri = 'XXX';
$permissions = array(XXX);
define( 'ROOT', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' );
require_once( ROOT . 'facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

// Initialize the SDK
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $app_id, $app_secret );
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $redirect_uri );

// Check if existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // Create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
    // Validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
    try {
      if ( ! $session->validate() ) {
        $session = null;
      }
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
      // Catch any exceptions
      $session = null;
    }
} else {
  // No session exists
  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {

    // When Facebook returns an error
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {

    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo $ex->message;
  }
}
// Check if a session exists
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // Save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // Create session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // Create the logout URL
  $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://msbooth.azurewebsites.net/' );
```

HERE IS THE PROBLEM SECTION:

```
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
        $session->destroySession();
        header('Location: ' . $helper->getLogoutUrl($session, 'XXX'));
    }
```

Any ideas on why the session won't destroy are welcome! I don't think i'm calling the action on the right object. Rest of the code below for reference.

```
} else {
  // No session - Get Login URL
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( $permissions );

  echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook</a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough this seems to have fixed the issue. Is this best practice or will this fail?

```
      // Create the logout URL (logout page should destroy the session)
  $logoutURL = $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://msbooth.azurewebsites.net/' );
  $redirectlogout = 'Location: ' . $helper->getLogoutUrl($session, 'http://msbooth.azurewebsites.net/');
  if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'logout'){
        session_destroy();
        header($redirectlogout);
    }
```